# About posting questions of high school level

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am new to this site. I just want to know  that if my question/doubt is of low level, i.e, from high school, is it ok to post it or not?

Comment: Hi, I improved the wording a bit. I hope it's ok with you. Please feel free to make changes as you deem necessary. Thank you!

Comment: More or less dupe of https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/fully-or-partially-handwritten-scanned-and-photographed-qas and https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/policy-on-questions-in-basic-mediums

Comment: @GaurangTandon thank you again sir :)

Comment: I'm sure this question is a duplicate of the first linked post, but since, the other part of this post talks about  "high school level problems", I'm not sure if we can close this as a dupe of the second linked post, considering that that post's conversations took place _before_ our previous homework policy was removed. It'd be best if OP edits their post to focus their question on high school level problems only.

Comment: @user190625 (see comment above) Please edit your post to focus on high school level problems only, as the first part has been directly addressed in https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3965/5026

Answer (score 6):

I'd argue that as long a question requires some thought to answer and the user shows some effort in attempting to determine that thought process, there really isn't such a thing as too low level of a question.

Some questions that don't require some thought (or anything beyond googling the answer) would be things like straight definitions, looking for random numeric values for certain compounds, etc.

The one thing I might look out for in asking a "low level" question is giving the context of how far along you are in learning chemistry. If you don't specify what you know, you can wind up getting an answer thats beyond your current level (ideally, questions will get answers at different levels anyway, but just to ensure you have a better chance of getting the answer you are looking for).